# How to : Read file from API (node) in my React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, file

I work on an webapp which use REACT JS (with NODE, port 3000) and an API (with NODE JS, port 3100). 
All requests made by client passing throught my API.

In this app, client could be able to listen mp3s downloaded and stored into my API. I made different schemas but I don't know which one can work.

---

SCHEMA 1.

- REACT send parameters to API
- API download the file and store it on a temporary directory
- API send the URL (like : http://localhost:3100/sound/exemple.mp3) to REACT
- REACT use that URL in 'src' of the AudioPlayer
- Temporary files are delete with a CRON setting up on API server

I tried that solution but I have an error when I want to play the sound 
(error: Can't GET /URL)

---

SCHEMA 2.

- REACT send parameters to API
- API download the file and store it on a temporary directory
- REACT download the file from API and store it into public directory (by using express static)
- REACT use that URL in 'src' of the AudioPlayer
- Delete the file twice (API and REACT)

---

Another solution is to download the file directly from my source on REACT. But I need to hide the URL of the source (that why I pass throught my API).

Maybe there are others solutions ?